# 401 Unauthorized Error on calling REST API from an Invokable Method called by flow

Tags: visual-workflow, apexrest

I have a flow and this flow calls an invokable method (where callout = true) that calls the Org REST API to update a Slack ViewDefinition.

The method works perfectly when called from an Anonymous Window. However, when called from a Flow, the HttpResponse Code and message are, respectively, 401 and "Unauthorized Error".

This is the code where I set the Http Request:

```
request.setEndpoint(
            URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
                '/services/data/v56.0/tooling/sobjects/ViewDefinition/' +
                VIEW_DEFINITION_ID
        );
request.setMethod('PATCH');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

You can notice I'm using the user session Id to authenticate.
As I said the InvokableMethod notation has callout = true.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible that you don't have a valid API session. Sessions that you obtain from the Lightning Experience do not have full API access, as a security measure. Try running the Flow from a Visualforce page, and it will most likely work, assuming you run it as a user with sufficient permissions.

Comment: Man ... you're Brilliant! It worked. Thank you!